# Disable a stage in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to temporary disable some stages in Jenkinsfile. Removing them and then restoring from version history seems like too much hasssle.
I tried adding this:

```
    stage('Tests') {
      when {
        false
      }
    (...)
```

But results in an error when I trigger the job:

```
WorkflowScript: 30: Expected a when condition @ line 30, column 7.

         when {

         ^

WorkflowScript: 30: Empty when closure, remove the property or add some content. @ line 30, column 7.

         when {
```

Is there a way to do `when: never` in Jenkins declarative pipelines?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can evaluate a boolean expression to disable the stage. Furthermore you could simply remove the stage or comment it out.

```
 stage('Tests') {
      when {
        expression { false }
      }
    ...
```

Comment: I discovered `when { expression { false } }` is enough, thx

Comment: Add `beforeAgent true` to not even display it any more in the stage view.

Comment: beforeAgent true still keeps the stage view sadly